# How to set the value of date input in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I created an angular js app which gets the customer data from the database using the customer id saved in the cookie and sets the fetched data in the `$scope` using the `initialize()` function. But the problem is that the birth date of the customer cannot be set in the `input` of type date. I receive error says something like Error: [ngModel:datefmt].
How can I set the fetched date in the form input?

Just in case if you need to know, I used DATE_FORMAT('birth_date', '%M %d, %Y') as birth_date in MySQL statement to fetch the date.

The code is given below.

Account.php

```
<?php $customer = (new Customer())->fetch_data($_COOKIE['customer-id']); ?>
<div id="account-settings" ng-app="settings"  ng-controller="personal-data" 
    ng-init="initialize()">

    <div id="ausweis-daten" class="header">
    <h4>Identity Document</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <label>First Name: </label>
        <input type="text" class="text-box" ng-model="firstname" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name">

        <label>Last Name: </label>
        <input type="text" class="text-box" ng-model="lastname" name="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
        <br/>
        <label>Date of Birth: </label>
        <input type="date" class="text-box" name="birth_date" ng-model="birth_date" placeholder="Date of Birth">
        <br/>
        <label>Place of Birth: </label>
        <input type="text" class="text-box" name="birth_place" ng-model="birth_place" placeholder="Place of Birth"><br/>
        <input type="submit" class="save-button" name="submit" ng-click="save_id()" value="Done">
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular js file:

```
    var app = angular.module('settings',[]);

    app.controller('personal-data', function($scope, $http){


        $scope.initialize = function(){
            $scope.firstname = "<?php echo $customer['fname'] ?>";
            $scope.lastname = "<?php echo $customer['lname']; ?>";
            $scope.birth_date = "<?php echo $customer['birth_date']; ?>";
            $scope.birth_place = "<?php echo $customer['birth_place']; ?>";
        }

        $scope.save_id = function(){

            var send_obj = {
                firstname: $scope.firstname,
                lastname: $scope.lastname,
                birth_date:$scope.birth_date,
                birth_place:$scope.birth_place
            };

            $http.post("functions/_customer_action.php", send_obj).then(function(success){
                alert(success.data);
            });
        }       
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Text must be entered in a valid ISO-8601 date format `yyyy-MM-dd`.
For example: `2009-01-06`. use `DATE_FORMAT('birth_date', '%Y-%M-%d')`